# Why would Haskell infer a specific type (apparently) inconsistently?

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I'm in the process of writing a toy (physics) vector library and am having issues with GHC insisting functions should have `Integer`s in their type. I want vectors to multiply vectors, as well as scalars (just using `*`), and while this was possible by just having `Vector` instance `Num` I'm now getting errors of the sort:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Integer' with actual type `Double'
```

After playing around with the code in order to pin down the problem I've gotten it down to this:

```
data V a = V a a a deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)
scale a (V i j k) = V (a*i) (a*j) (a*k)
(<.>) = scale
```

Now if we ask GHCi what type these are we get:

```
>:t scale
scale :: Num a => a -> V a -> V a
>:t (<.>)
(<.>) :: Integer -> V Integer -> V Integer
```

Where we certainly don't want `<.>` only acting on `Integer`s. While this is fixable here by including a type signature for `<.>`, I would like to know what's actually going on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the monomorphism restriction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are running into the infamous [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction). Another solution would be to specify arguments explicitly:

```
a <.> v = scale a v
```

Or add `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` pragma.

Comment: ... or add a type signature. Type signatures on all top-level functions is considered good style anyway, so this is my preferred way of avoiding monomorphism restriction-related issues.