# When is my Haskell expression evaluated?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

If I define

```
λ> data Bar = Bar Int deriving Show
λ> data Foo = Foo Bar deriving Show
```

and

```
λ> let foo = trace "foo" Foo (trace "bar" Bar 100)
λ> let two = trace "two" 2
λ> let g (Foo x)  y = y
```

then I think I understand why I get

```
λ> g foo two
foo
two
2
```

But if I then repeat this, I get

```
λ> g foo two
two
2
```

and I don't understand why `foo` appears not to have been evaluated for the second invocation of `g`, especially since it is clearly not (yet) somehow already available, as I can verify with

```
λ> foo
Foo bar
(Bar 100)
```

though — again, to my confusion — repeating the previous gives

```
λ> foo
Foo (Bar 100)
```

Why does my `foo` expression  appear to be already evaluated in some cases, and not evaluated in others? And for that matter why does my `two` expression *always* need to be evaluated?

Comment: `two` probably stays unevaluated because of its type, `(Num a) => a`. The literal `2` is secretly `fromInteger 2`, and the exact `fromInteger` function used depends on the type expected by the surrounding context.

Comment: @melpomene: Interesting! That makes sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's due to `two`'s type. Lets check all the type's so far:

```
ghci> :t foo
foo :: Foo
ghci> :t two
two :: Num a => a
```

Aha! `two` is polymorphic. Therefore, its behaviour depends on the *actual `Num` instance*. Therefore, it needs to get re-evaluated in `g`. We can check this by using `:sprint`:

```
ghci> :sprint foo
foo = Foo _             -- simplified
```

Which indicates that we never looked at the contents of `Foo`. `foo` is in [weak head normal form](https://wiki.haskell.org/Weak_head_normal_form). This answers your second question. But back to your first. What happens on `:sprint two`?

```
ghci> :sprint two
two = _
```

As you can see, due to its polymorphic nature, `two` doesn't get to WHNF. After all, *which* WHNF should it take? You might want to use it as `Integer`, or `Currency`, or `Complex Triple`.

This is, by the way, a reason for the existence of the monomorphism restriction, see ["A History of Haskell", section 6.2](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/history-of-haskell/history.pdf):

> ### 6.2 The monomorphism restriction
>
> A major source of controversy in the early stages was the so-called
>   “monomorphism restriction.” Suppose that `genericLength` has
>   this overloaded type:
>
> ```
> genericLength` :: Num a => [b] -> a
> ```
>
> Now consider this definition:
>
> ```
> f xs = (len, len)
>   where
>     len = genericLength xs
> ```
>
> It looks as if len should be computed only once, but it can actually be computed twice. Why? Because we can infer the type
>   `len :: (Num a) => a`; when desugared with the dictionary-
>   passing translation, `len` becomes a function that is called once
>   for each occurrence of `len`, each of which might used at a different
>   type.

See also [this Q&A for more information about the restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction).

That being said, we can easily change this if we fix `two`'s type:

```
ghci> let foo = trace "foo" Foo (trace "bar" Bar 100)
ghci> let two = trace "two" (2 :: Integer)
ghci> let g (Foo x)  y = y
```

Now the output will be exactly as you've expected. Alternatively, you can enable the monomorphism restriction with `:set -XMonomorphismRestriction`, as it is disabled in current GHCi versions by default:

```
ghci> :set -XMonomorphismRestriction
ghci> let two = trace "two" 2
ghci> :t two
two :: Integer -- due to defaulting rules
```

Comment: That clears things up, except that the name is a but confusing, so just to be sure: With the restriction *disabled*, types like the that for the `two` example will *not* be inferred, and will thus remain polymorphic (so that they will be recomputed when a type is imposed).

Answer (score 5):

```
> :t foo
foo :: Foo
> :t two
two :: Num a => a
```

The second one is *polymorphic*, so it's a function in disguise! Every time you use it, you will evaluate a new `trace` call.

Comment: Aha! And `foo` is "available" once it has been evaluated once (at the top level) — i.e., it doesn't need to be evaluated again (at least not as far as it already has been)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius The "as far as it already has been" is exactly the important part in `foo's` case. You can check this with `:sprint`: `let k = map Bar [1..100]; length k; :sprint k` (replace the semicolons with enter during your GHCi session).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Yes. Since it has a monomorphic type, and is bound at the top-level it will be evaluated once. Note that this is a choice of GHCi, not one mandated by the Haskell report.