# Types required to be equivalent across two separate function calls

Tags: haskell, types, ghci, type-systems

Consider the following two functions in Haskell (a minimal example of my real code):

```
printSequence :: (Show a, Show b) => a -> b -> IO ()
printSequence x y = (putStr . show) x >> (putStr . show) y

printSequence' :: (Show a, Show b) => a -> b -> IO ()
printSequence' x y = print' x >> print' y
    where print' = putStr . show
```

The first compiles fine, but the second produces the error:

```
 Could not deduce (a ~ b)
    from the context (Show a, Show b)
      bound by the type signature for
                 printSequence' :: (Show a, Show b) => a -> b -> IO ()
      at test.hs:8:19-53
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            printSequence' :: (Show a, Show b) => a -> b -> IO ()
          at test.hs:8:19
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            printSequence' :: (Show a, Show b) => a -> b -> IO ()
          at test.hs:8:19
    In the first argument of print', namely `y'
    In the second argument of `(>>)', namely `(print' y)'
    In the expression: (print' x) >> (print' y)
```

I understand this error to mean that GHC is requiring `x` and `y` to be of equivalent type. What I do not understand is WHY. Statements like `print "fish" >> print 3.14` work perfectly fine in the interpreter, so why does GHC complain about `x` and `y` being different types when I call my `print'` function two separate times?

Comment: About the dreaded Monomorphism Restriction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an explicit type signature:

```
printSequence' :: (Show a, Show b) => a -> b -> IO ()
printSequence' x y = print' x >> print' y
    where
    print' :: Show a => a -> IO ()
    print' = putStr . show
```

or use [**`NoMonomorphismRestriction`**](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction):

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

printSequence' :: (Show a, Show b) => a -> b -> IO ()
printSequence' x y = print' x >> print' y
    where
    print' = putStr . show
```

then,

```
\> printSequence' 5 "five"
5"five"
```

Comment: This works when copied verbatim, but I have a follow-up question regarding your first solution. Why does it fail when I provide the type signature in the same line, like `where print' = (putStr . show) :: Show a => a -> IO ()` ?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish That's annotating the value on the right-hand side of the = sign, leaving GHC to infer the type of the name on the left-hand side. GHC infers monomorphic types for patterns without explicit function arguments, and declaring a polymorphic type on the right doesn't change that rule.