# Haskell newbie gotcha: why does this η-reduction change type inference?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, type-inference, static-typing

Learning Haskell right now and stumbled upon this oddity. Consider:

```
main = do
    print $ mysquare 2
    print $ mysquare 2.0
```

Output with

```
-- style A:
mysquare x = x * x
```

is **4** and **4.0**. Likewise, output with

```
-- style B:
mysquare x = x ^ 2
```

is **4** and **4.0**. But output with

```
-- style C:
mysquare = (^2)
```

is **4.0** and **4.0**.

I wouldn't have expected from my beginner understanding so far that η-reducing style B into style C would silently change the Int into a Fractional. Why does that occur?

Comment: Look up the monomorphism restriction.

Comment: The dreaded monomorphism restriction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction