# Implementation of quick sort using haskel

Tags: haskell

I was wondering why my quick sort code below shows the 'Unresolved top-level overloading error'

```
sort = \xs -> case xs of
                [] -> []
                y:ys -> sort[p | p <- ys, p < y]
                        ++ y:sort[p| p <- ys, p > y]
```

Can you let me know why?

Comment: Is this all the code in your file? This snippet own it's own gives me a different error

Comment: Also, are you using GHC or Hugs?

Comment: @shree.pat18 yes

Comment: @WillNess I got the type inference error due to use of < and > on GHCI, but not the one OP did. Agree that might just be Hugs

Comment: @shree.pat18 I deleted my comment since reading the answer, which links to an answer about monomorphism restriction. I might have a flag set in my ghci that prevents the error, or maybe it's version dependent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of this function cannot be inferred, because there are multiple types possible with the constraint that `<` and `>` are used. You can fix this by adding a signature such as below (as general as possible). Btw your implementation deletes recurring elements. Using `<=` instead of `<`fixes this:

```
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort = \xs -> case xs of
                [] -> []
                y:ys -> sort[p | p <- ys, p <= y]
                        ++ y:sort[p| p <- ys, p > y]
```

Example call (double 7's):

```
> sort [12,34,2,4,7,6,34,7,3]
[2,3,4,6,7,7,12,34,34]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I changed my code not using lambda then it worked without adding 'sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]'. Can you let me know why?

Comment: This is because the binding and type inference is handled differently. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37169791/14627587) and [this very long answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32496865/14627587).