# Issues adding fractional types

Tags: haskell

I am trying to define a function that requires me to add a fractional type to a double but I seem to receive an error.

```
epsilon = 0.0000001
dif :: (Fractional a) => (a->a) -> a -> a

dif f x = (f(x+epsilon)-f(x))/epsilon
```

Haskell seems to be having trouble interpreting x+epsilon but this seems odd considering that x is defined to be a Fractional type in the function declaration and epsilon is a double (which is a part of the Fractional type class?

Heres the error I get:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Double’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for dif :: Fractional a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
      at dif.hs:3:8
Relevant bindings include
  x :: a (bound at dif.hs:5:7)
  f :: a -> a (bound at dif.hs:5:5)
  dif :: (a -> a) -> a -> a (bound at dif.hs:5:1)
In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘epsilon’
In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘(x + epsilon)’
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give `epsilon` a suitably polymorphic type signature:

```
epsilon :: Fractional a => a
```

You may also like the explanations in [What is the monomorphism restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction).

Comment: In particular, `epsilon` is a Double, so `dif` will work only with `a ~ Double`. However, the type signature promises to work for *any* `Fractional a`, and the compiler is noting that your implementation doesn't live up to this promise, because it depends on `dif`.