# How does GHCi pick an instance of the Monad type class to use for polymorphic actions?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm new to Haskell so this might be a noob question.

When I do `return 10 >>= return` GHCi shows `10`. When I check the type of `return 10` with `:t` it just says `return 10 :: (Monad m, Num a) => m a`, and of I do `typeOf return 10` I get an error.

But as far as I understand, Haskell must have used a particular instance of `>>=` to evaluate `return 10 >>= return`, so which instance did it use and how did it decide which one to use?

Comment: I temporarily closed this as a duplicate of "[What is the monomorphism restriction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction)". That question addresses how a `Num` instance is chosen for `a`, but I think does not address how a `Monad` instance is chosen for `m`. So I think it is not quite a duplicate, and deserves a careful answer.

Comment: Actually I'm asking how a particular instance of monad is chosen for a generic monad. I'm guessing it used list's `>>=` but I'm not sure why.

Comment: I suspect it might be the IO-monad. Normally ghci tries to `print` the REPL result, but if it encounters an IO-action it _executes_ it instead and prints the result returned by the action. A type like `(Monad m, Num a) => m a` is compatible with `IO a`, and perhaps that is criteria it is using to decide whether to execute vs. print the current REPL expression.

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with monomorphism restriction, but is a combination of Int for defaulting (https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4) and using the io monad as repl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This follows the idea that GHCi is sort of like a giant `do` block of `IO`.  Whenever you type in something that is an expression it first tries to see if the type of the result can be specialized to something of the form `IO a`. If it can, it executes the `IO` action and just prints the result. Only otherwise does it print the result of the expression itself.

To force GHCi to go to whatever specific monad you want, you can add a type annotation. Notice how `IO` gets treated differently (and the same way as the expression would have been treated without any annotation).

```
ghci> return 10 >>= return :: Maybe Int
Just 10
ghci> return 10 >>= return :: [Int]
[10]
ghci> return 10 >>= return :: IO Int
10
```

---

As an aside, there is an entirely different problem regarding what instance of `Num` is chosen, and that one has everything to do with defaulting rules and the monomorphism restriction.

Comment: So using any ambiguous expression that uses a typeclass other than the monad should give me an error instead of picking a default one?

Comment: @Juan, if for instance I type `return mempty` in `ghci` I get an ambiguous type error, so if I understand your question correctly, then yes.

Comment: But `mempty` (without the `return`) works and defaults to the `()` type

Comment: @Juan No; see the question I [linked above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction) for details on the extended defaulting rules that are in play in ghci. If it is ambiguous, doesn't use `Monad`, and those rules don't apply, *then* you should get an error.

Comment: @Fabian Check out [this](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html) and search for `-XExtendedDefaultRules`. Note the third point "The unit type () is added to the start of the standard list of types which are tried when doing type defaulting" and the fact that we have a `Monoid` instance for `IO` and for `()`