# Why does using lambda notation in Haskell result in a different type signature?

Tags: haskell, types, lambda

I wrote what I think is the same function in the following three ways:

```
addThree x y z = x + y + z
addThree' = \x y z -> x + y + z
addThree'' = \x -> \y -> \z -> x + y + z
```

Yet when I load and check their types in GHCi using `:t`, it gives me a very weird answer:

```
addThree :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> a
addThree' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
addThree'' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

Why do the lambdas have different, specialized types while the normal one has the correct type?

Comment: Good intuition that these should be the same.  This is a special case called the monomorphism restriction which you can read about by googling

Comment: Presumably you are using a version of ghci before 7.8.1?

Comment: @luqui: There's a [very exhaustive answer by Bakuriu](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32496864/1139697), so feel free to close questions like this as duplicate of theirs.