# confused about dot-operator in haskell

Tags: haskell

```
(head.group) "1234"
```

It work.

```
head.group "1234"
```

I get errors:

```
<interactive>:8:6:
Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> [c0]'
            with actual type `[[Char]]'
In the return type of a call of `group'
Probable cause: `group' is applied to too many arguments
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `group "1234"'
In the expression: head . group "1234"
```

I think (head.group) is same as head.group, why (head.group) work and head.group not.

Comment: I think part of the confusion may be resulting from the unorthodox formatting of your code. What you've written as `head.group "1234"` would normally be written equivalently as `head . group "1234"`. Also, just in case this isn't already clear, it's important to understand that `.` is not a special construct in the language; it is [an ordinary function](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.20/base-4.9.1.0/Prelude.html#v:.).

Comment: @ChrisMartin But as soon as `.` is in infix position, it is evaluated as an operator, right? And normal function application has precedence over operators. So `(.) head group "1234"` would work.

Comment: @ftor right, because `(.) head group "1234"` is the same as `(((.) head) group) "1234" = ((.) head group) "1234" = (head . group) "1234"`.

Answer (score 4):

Because

```
(head . group) "1234" = f "12345"
  where
    f = head . group
```

whereas

```
head . group "1234" = head . (group "1234") 
                    = head . f
  where
    f = group "1234"
```

but `group "1234"` isn't a function. Remember, function application binds stronger than operators.

Comment: Thank you. A anthor question, why let f = head.group, f  [1,2, 3] get a error

Comment: this is the error info: <interactive>:4:4:
    No instance for (Num ()) arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num ())
    In the expression: 1
    In the first argument of `f', namely `[1, 2, 3]'
    In the expression: f [1, 2, 3]

Comment: That's the [monomorphism restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction). It should not happen in GHCi. Please not that interpreted code slightly differs from compiled one.

Comment: Maybe mentioning the term [composition](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.20/base-4.9.1.0/Prelude.html#v:.) in your answer would be informative.