# Haskell type specifier issue using integral and int

Tags: haskell, types

I have the following Haskell definitions in a source file

```
nNotes=7

pitchLimit k = k < 0 || k > 20  
pitcherror = error "Invalid Pitch"

getOctave k
    | pitchLimit k = pitcherror
    | otherwise = k `div` nNotes
```

I do not declare the type of `getOctave`. Now here is my issue regarding types. Later on in the same source file, I used `getOctave` with an `Int`. I load the source file into GHCI and Haskell infers that the type of `getOctave` is `Int->Int`. Now I comment out the code that uses `getOctave` as an `Int`. I reload the source file and now Haskell infers `getOctave` to be of type `Integer->Integer`. Seems to me now that the default of `div` is `Integer->Integer`. Now I uncomment that code and specify the type of `getOctave` to be `(Integral a) => a  ->a`. And Haskell reports an error. What's wrong with using `(Integral a) => a -> a`.

Comment: Probably a consequence of the monomorphism restriction. Non function bindings like `x=4` are only given monomorphic types if not explicitly annotated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction

Answer (score 3):

When you use a literal like `7`, GHC tries to guess which type you meant. You can reproduce this with a `.hs` file that (apart from a `module` declaration) contains only

```
nNotes = 7
```

This will give you the compiler warning:

```
* Defaulting the following constraint to type `Integer'
    Num t0 arising from the literal `7'
* In the expression: 7
  In an equation for `nNotes': nNotes = 7
```

From there, the compiler will infer all the other types.

You can generalise your code by explicitly annotate `nNotes` with a type, like this:

```
nNotes :: Num a => a
nNotes = 7
```

Once you do that, your functions get these automatically inferred types:

```
λ: :type pitchLimit
pitchLimit :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> Bool
λ: :type getOctave
getOctave :: Integral t => t -> t
```

As you can see, `getOctave` can take any `Integral` as input, including both `Integer` and `Int`.

The reason that `getOctave` infers `t` to be of the class `Integral` is because `div` is defined for `Integral`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem here is you have to also declare nNotes to be of type `nNotes :: Integral a => a`.

Comment: That's interesting. I forgot about nNotes. Haskell infers the type of it to be `Int`. Why?

Comment: @johnson When I load the source file in ghci, it looks like it assumes nNotes is `Integer`. When you had something else of type `Int` in the code, the compiler probably realised nNotes had to be `Int`. My guess is that, unless contradicted, the compiler assumes integer literal definitions should be `Integer`. In which case it might be a bug with GHC if it can't automatically infer that you want nNotes to be of type `Integral a => a` (but I don't know much about compilers).