# Why can the haskell compiler infer this type but ghci cannot?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm working through the [following book](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) to learn Haskell - looking in particular at the chapter on [randomness](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#randomness):

I'm running the following as the file `three-coins.hs`:

```
import System.Random 

threeCoins :: StdGen -> (Bool, Bool, Bool)  
threeCoins gen =   
    let (firstCoin, newGen) = random gen
        (secondCoin, newGen') = random newGen
        (thirdCoin, newGen'') = random newGen'
    in  (firstCoin, secondCoin, thirdCoin)

main = print ( threeCoins (mkStdGen 21) )
```

Which I then execute with `runhaskell three-coins.hs` and get output similar to:

```
(True,True,True)
```

Now they make the point in the notes:

> Notice that we didn't have to do `random gen :: (Bool, StdGen)`. That's because we already specified that we want booleans in the type declaration of the function. That's why Haskell can infer that we want a boolean value in this case.

That is cool.

Now when I run this in `ghci` with the following code:

```
import System.Random 

:{
threeCoins :: StdGen -> (Bool, Bool, Bool)
threeCoins gen =
    let (firstCoin, newGen) = random gen
        (secondCoin, newGen') = random newGen
        (thirdCoin, newGen'') = random newGen'
    in  (firstCoin, secondCoin, thirdCoin)
:}
```

I get the following response:

```
<interactive>:6:9: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Random t0)’ from being solved.
    • When checking that the inferred type
        newGen :: forall t. Random t => StdGen
      is as general as its inferred signature
        newGen :: StdGen
      In the expression:
        let
          (firstCoin, newGen) = random gen
          (secondCoin, newGen') = random newGen
          (thirdCoin, newGen'') = random newGen'
        in (firstCoin, secondCoin, thirdCoin)
      In an equation for ‘threeCoins’:
          threeCoins gen
            = let
                (firstCoin, newGen) = random gen
                (secondCoin, newGen') = random newGen
                ....
              in (firstCoin, secondCoin, thirdCoin)
```

Which is interesting. Somewhat like the error they were warning us about in the book.

So if we modify the code to put the type hints in:

```
import System.Random 

:{
threeCoins :: StdGen -> (Bool, Bool, Bool)
threeCoins gen =
    let (firstCoin, newGen) = random gen :: (Bool, StdGen)
        (secondCoin, newGen') = random newGen :: (Bool, StdGen)
        (thirdCoin, newGen'') = random newGen' :: (Bool, StdGen)
    in  (firstCoin, secondCoin, thirdCoin)
:}
```

That works fine - and we can test it with the following:

```
threeCoins (mkStdGen 21)
```

and get this result

```
(True,True,True)
```

Huh - that worked. So the Haskell compiler can infer from the type that we provided that we want a boolean, but ghci can't.

My question is: **Why can the haskell compiler infer this type but ghci cannot?**

Comment: `:set -XMonomorphismRestriction` makes this work in GHCi as well. GHCi disables the MR, unlike GHC (the compiler), but in this case it is beneficial, so you can turn it back on. Essentially, `newGen` is given a too general type, which causes the ambiguity later on.

Comment: Cool - why does ghci disable the monomorphism restriction ?

Comment: Because especially on the REPL, the defaulting to a specific type is more often a pain than a benefit.

Comment: In most cases, the MR makes the code less likely to type-check, assigning monomorphic types when they could be generalized to polymorphic ones. The MR was introduced to improve performance in some cases, where computation could be duplicated as in `let x = 10*10 in x+x` which causes `10*10` to be computed twice without the MR (or an explicit annotation). This comes at the cost of typeability. Some argue that MR should be disabled in Haskell by default, but this breaks retro-compatibility, so for now GHC keeps it on. GHCi, instead, turns it off to improve convenience.

Comment: Anyway, the MR is a relatively complex thing, with subtle consequences. It is described in some detail at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction

Comment: @chi you should probably put this in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As chi already commented, this code only works when the [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/MonomorphismRestriction) is enabled. That restriction makes the compiler choose *one specific type* for any non-function definition, i.e. a signature with no type variables in it like the `a` in `length :: [a] -> Int`. So (unless you've manually specified a local signature) the compiler looks around everywhere for a hint what this type could be, before it chooses. In your example, it sees that `firstCoin` `secondCoin` `thirdCoin` are used in the final result which at the top-level signature is declared `(Bool, Bool, Bool)`, so it infers that all the coins must have type `Bool`.

That's nice and fine in such a simple example, but in modern Haskell, you very often need values to be more general, so you can use them in multiple different-typed contexts or as arguments for Rank-2 function. You can always achieve this by giving explicit signatures, but especially in GHCi that's awkward (it's regularly called “the *Dreaded* Monomorphism Restriction”), therefore it was decided a couple of versions ago to disable it by default in GHCi.

*Conceptually*, `firstCoin` `secondCoin` `thirdCoin` etc. could also be more general than `Bool`: `random` is after all able to yield random values of *any* suitable type (i.e. any type that has a [`Random`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#t:Random) instance). So in principle, the local definitions could have a polymorphic type, like this:

```
threeCoins :: StdGen -> (Bool, Bool, Bool)  
threeCoins gen =   
    let firstCoin, secondCoin, thirdCoin :: Random r => r
        (firstCoin, newGen) = random gen
        (secondCoin, newGen') = random newGen
        (thirdCoin, newGen'') = random newGen'
    in  (firstCoin, secondCoin, thirdCoin)
```

which is basically what happens when the monomorphism restriction is turned off, as you can see by compiling your original example with the line

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

on top.

Trouble is, your code doesn't actually work with those general local signatures. The reason is a bit involved, it's basically that the type information of the `r` variable has to be propagated back into a tuple before it can be used in the `random` generator, and for reasons that I right now don't understand either, the Hindley-Milner type system can't do that.

The best solution is to *not* do this manual tuple unwrapping, which is anyways awkward, but instead use a [random monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.2.7.0/docs/Data-Random.html), like this:

```
import System.Random 
import Data.Random 

threeCoins :: RVar (Bool, Bool, Bool)  
threeCoins = do   
    firstCoin <- uniform False True
    secondCoin <- uniform False True
    thirdCoin <- uniform False True
    return (firstCoin, secondCoin, thirdCoin)

main = print . sampleState threeCoins $ mkStdGen 21
```

which works with or without momomorphism restriction, because `firstCoin` `secondCoin` `thirdCoin` now come from a monadic bind, [which is *always* monomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism#Predicativity_and_impredicativity).

Incidentally, because you're in a monad then you can use standard combinators and thus easily shorten it to

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

threeCoins :: RVar (Bool, Bool, Bool)  
threeCoins = do   
    [firstCoin,secondCoin,thirdCoin] <- replicateM 3 $ uniform False True
    return (firstCoin, secondCoin, thirdCoin)
```

Comment: Those polymorphic signatures have no hope of working. The pattern bindings lead to trouble because you can't simply extract a `forall r. r` from a `forall r. (r,a)`. Furthermore, there's syntactically just one `r`, but that expands to three unrelated type variables. Question: do you need the full MR, or will `MonoLocalBinds` do the trick?