# Why is GHCi accepting something at the prompt that won't compile?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm trying to play around with Haskell types, creating a data taking a type constructor and a concrete type (inspired by [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#the-functor-typeclass)).

Here is my kung.hs file:

```
data Kung t a = Kung { field :: t a } deriving (Show, Eq)

val1 = Kung { field = [1,5] }

val2 = Kung { field =  Just 3 }

--val3 = Kung { field =  3 }
```

It compiles fine and loads ok:

```
*Main> :load C:\Test\Haskell\kung.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C:\Test\Haskell\kung.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> val1
Kung {field = [1,5]}
*Main> val2
Kung {field = Just 3}
*Main>
```

Now the same version, but uncommenting `val3`:

```
data Kung t a = Kung { field :: t a } deriving (Show, Eq)

val1 = Kung { field = [1,5] }

val2 = Kung { field =  Just 3 }

val3 = Kung { field =  3 }
```

This does not compile :

```
*Main> :load C:\Test\Haskell\kung.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C:\Test\Haskell\kung.hs, interpreted )

C:\Test\Haskell\kung.hs:7:24: error:
    * No instance for (Num (t0 a0)) arising from the literal `3'
    * In the `field' field of a record
      In the expression: Kung {field = 3}
      In an equation for `val3': val3 = Kung {field = 3}
  |
7 | val3 = Kung { field =  3 }
  |                        ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

which seems fine. There is no way to "decompose" / "construct"  (maybe not the right terminology used here)  the value `3` of type `Num` from  some type constructor and some concrete type.

Going back to the GHCi interpreter, load the first version of the file without the `val3` commented and then:

```
Prelude> :load C:\Test\Haskell\kung.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C:\Test\Haskell\kung.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> val3 = Kung { field =  3 }
*Main> :t val3
val3 :: Num (t a) => Kung t a
```

How should I understand that? Why did GHCi artificially "manage" to decompose `3`? (without giving a real type)

Then this `val3` does not really seem viable:

```
*Main> val3

<interactive>:50:1: error:
    * Ambiguous type variables `t0', `a0' arising from a use of `print'
      prevents the constraint `(Show (t0 a0))' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `t0', `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance (Show b, Show a) => Show (Either a b)
          -- Defined in `Data.Either'
        instance [safe] Show (t a) => Show (Kung t a)
          -- Defined at C:\Test\Haskell\kung.hs:1:49
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
        ...plus 15 others
        ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
*Main>
```

What is the subtlety happening here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the Dreaded Monomorphism Restriction at work. The following compiles fine:

```
data Kung t a = Kung { field :: t a } deriving (Show, Eq)

val3 :: Num (t a) => Kung t a
val3 = Kung { field =  3 }
```

however, the [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) prevents GHC from inferring this signature itself. Instead, it tries to find a *monomorphic* type. For this it only has the Haskell *defaulting rules* available. Normally, these imply that a `Num`-constrained type variable is monomorphised to `Integer`... but integer is not of the form `t a`, so this fails.

The *correct* fix is to, indeed, write the type signature yourself, but you can also turn off the monomorphism restriction:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

data Kung t a = Kung { field :: t a } deriving (Show, Eq)

val3 = Kung { field =  3 }
```

In GHCi, the monomorphism restriction is turned off by default since, GHC-7.8 I believe it was. That's why the problem doesn't arise there.

Answer (score 1):

Your `val3` is generic. It's a generic value of type `Kung t a`, where `t` and `a` are not known yet. GHCi accepts it fine, because it can hold onto it and wait until you supply the concrete `t` and `a`. And indeed, as soon as you try to use the value (by printing it out) without supplying the types, GHCi bails on you.

But GHC cannot afford to "hold on": it needs to know the types in order to finish compilation.

You could remedy the situation by telling the compiler explicitly that you would like to have yourself a generic value, which could later be consumed by a consumer, who would be willing to supply suitable types. To do this, use a type annotation:

```
val3 :: Num (t a) => Kung t a
val3 = Kung { field = 3 }
```

Behind the scenes, such definition would be compiled as a function that takes a dictionary `Num (t a)` and returns a value of type `Kung t a`.

---

To answer the question "*how did GHCi manage to "decompose"/"deconstruct" the value 3*" (I'm adding this answer here, but I'm not sure if that's what you're asking).

Number literals are polymorphic in Haskell as well. When you write `3`, the compiler understands that as `fromInteger (3::Integer)`, where `fromInteger` is a function from the `Num` class. This means that, theoretically, a literal `3` may have any type at all, as long as that type has a `Num` instance defined.

So when you write something `Kung { field = 3 }`, the compiler sees that as `Kung { field = fromInteger 3 }`, and this could very well be of any type `Kung t a`, if only the compiler could prove that there is a `Num` instance for type `t a`, which it can use to convert `3` to `t a`.

Comment: (1) Nitpicking: the change in behaviour with respect to "hold[ing]" on is not due to an essential difference between GHCi and GHC, but rather due to [the monomorphism restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32496864/2751851), which is enabled by default for compiled programs but not in GHCi. If you turn it on in GHCi (with `:set -XMonomorphismRestriction`), you get the other behaviour. (2) For an example of something with a `Num (t a)` instance that fits `val3`, see [`Sum` and `Product` from `Data.Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#g:3).