# How to pass from a do notation to a (>>=) operator notation?

Tags: haskell, monads

I can not really understand why such line of code actually work :

From  [Network.HTTP.Simple](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.3.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Simple.html)

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Simple
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8

main :: IO ()
main = httpBS "http://example.com" >>= B8.putStrLn . getResponseBody
```

I am able to rewrite the stuff with do notation :

```
test = do
          request <- return "http://example.com"
          result <- httpBS request
          let body = getResponseBody result
          B8.putStrLn body
```

This works, even If I cannot figure out what is the type of `return "http://example.com"`.

Q1 : How the compiler manage to find which Monad I want to use ?

My guess is : it is coming up from the fact that return of the do block is an IO() and so it would be an IO (Request) ?

Now, When trying to use httpBS in more complex code, I have some difficulties

test.hs file  :

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.HTTP.Simple
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8


request = parseRequest "http://example.com"
```

this gives the error :

```
Prelude> :load test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:8:11: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `m0' arising from a use of `parseRequest'
      prevents the constraint `(Control.Monad.Catch.MonadThrow
                                  m0)' from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        request :: m0 Request (bound at test.hs:8:1)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `m0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance e ~ GHC.Exception.SomeException =>
                 Control.Monad.Catch.MonadThrow (Either e)
          -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Catch'
        instance Control.Monad.Catch.MonadThrow IO
          -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Catch'
        instance Control.Monad.Catch.MonadThrow Maybe
          -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Catch'
        ...plus one other
        ...plus 15 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In the expression: parseRequest "http://example.com"
      In an equation for `request':
          request = parseRequest "http://example.com"
  |
8 | request = parseRequest "http://example.com"
  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Ok. Entering same stuff in the interpreter works  :

```
*Main Network.HTTP.Simple> import Network.HTTP.Simple
*Main Network.HTTP.Simple> req = parseRequest "http://example.com"
*Main Network.HTTP.Simple> :t req
req :: Control.Monad.Catch.MonadThrow m => m Request
*Main Network.HTTP.Simple> req
Request {
  host                 = "example.com"
  port                 = 80
  secure               = False
  requestHeaders       = []
  path                 = "/"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
```

It looks like the dreaded monomorphic restriction stuff that I already stumble accross  [c.f this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49693687/why-is-ghci-accepting-something-at-the-prompt-that-wont-compile)

So I understand I have to give the type.It's ok but then I can not figure out how to use it with the >>= notation , I can only manage to have it working with the do notation :

```
-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.HTTP.Simple
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8

url  = "http://example.com"
maybeRequest :: Maybe Request
maybeRequest = parseRequest url 

ioRequest :: IO Request
ioRequest = parseRequest url

--no. wrong type ioRequest.
--testKO = httpBS ioRequest >>= B8.putStrLn . getResponseBody

--How to have it working with a one-liner and  the >>= notation ? 

--do notation ok
test = do 
        request <- ioRequest
        response <- httpBS request
        let body = getResponseBody response
        B8.putStrLn body
```

Q2 : how to use the Request and httpBS  with the (>>=) operator  if the Request is to be build previously ?

Comment: Well `do` notation is actually syntactical sugar for the notation with bind (`>>=`), etc. So as some sort of first step, Haskell rewrites your `do` notation to something like the previous sample (although here you actually used a `return` too much).

Comment: The desugaring is specified in Chapter 14 of "*Real World Haskell*": http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html#monads.do

Comment: The [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/) also does a good job of explaining just how [`do` expressions](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) desugar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I cannot figure out what is the type of `return "http://example.com"`

Fortunately, GHCi can:

```
> :t return "http://example.com"
return "http://example.com" :: Monad m => m [Char]
```

So it's a valid monad action for any monad that returns a String.

Since `return` is part of the Monad type class definition, this should not be a surprise.

> Q1 : How the compiler manage to find which Monad I want to use ?

It uses type inference. Being inside a do-block constrains this to a monad by default and so does `return "..."`. ([`RebindableSyntax`](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-06-rebindable-syntax.html) lets you overload the implicit `(>>=)` of do-blocks to any operator, but that's not something you see often.)

The action `httpBS :: MonadIO m => Request -> m (Response ByteString)` further constrains this to something called [`MonadIO m`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html), which is apparently a special kind of Monad that has `liftIO :: Monad m => IO a -> m a`. The simplest example of a `MonadIO m` is `IO`, but the compiler hasn't concretized this yet.

Finally, [`B8.putStrLn :: ByteString -> IO ()`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:putStrLn) constrains `test :: IO ()`.

> Q2 : how to use the Request and httpBS with the (>>=) operator if the Request is to be build previously ? **How to have it working with a one-liner and  the >>= notation ?**

Both do-blocks and point-free one-liners can be convenient and slightly magical. You can bridge these two notations by de-sugaring a do-block and then perform [η-reduction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion). A good read for understanding do-notation is still Philip Wadler's [Monads for functional programming](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/marktoberdorf/baastad.pdf).

The following:

```
test = do
  request <- ioRequest
  response <- httpBS request
  B8.putStrLn (getResponseBody response)
```

de-sugars into:

```
test =
  ioRequest >>= \request ->
  httpBS request >>= \response ->
  B8.putStrLn (getResponseBody response)
```

But `B8.putStrLn (getResponseBody response)`
is `(B8.putStrLn . getResponseBody) response`.

*(The point of this transformation is to have both lambdas expressed as [`\x -> f x`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion).)*

So this becomes:

```
test =
  (ioRequest >>= \request -> httpBS request)
    >>= \response -> (B8.putStrLn . getResponseBody) response
```

- But `\request -> httpBS request` is just `httpBS`.
- And `\response -> (B8.putStrLn . getResponseBody) response`
  is just `B8.putStrLn . getResponseBody`.

So this becomes:

```
test =
  (ioRequest >>= httpBS)
    >>= B8.putStrLn . getResponseBody
```

Reformatting this to fit one line:

```
test = ioRequest >>= httpBS >>= B8.putStrLn . getResponseBody
```

Answer (score 3):

Q1: Every line of a do-block must be "in" *the same* monad. (That's why `maybeRequest` doesn't work; you can't mix the `Maybe` monad with the `IO` monad.)

Q2: Close, but not quite.

`ioRequest` is an I/O action, so you need to use `>>=` to fetch the request out of it:

```
test = ioRequest >>= httpBS >>= B8.putStrLn . getResponseBody
```

---

While I'm here, I'll also point out that

```
request <- return "http://example.com/"
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
let request = "http://example.com/"
```