# Haskell count length using foldr throw type error

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors, parametric-polymorphism, monomorphism-restriction

Trying to implement list counting through foldr function

```
lengthList = foldr (\x s -> s + 1) 0
```

gives following error

```
   * Ambiguous type variable `t0' arising from a use of `foldr'
  prevents the constraint `(Foldable t0)' from being solved.
  Relevant bindings include
    lengthList :: t0 a -> Integer (bound at lenListFoldr.hs:2:1)
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `t0' should be.
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Foldable (Either a) -- Defined in `Data.Foldable'
    instance Foldable Maybe -- Defined in `Data.Foldable'
    instance Foldable ((,) a) -- Defined in `Data.Foldable'
    ...plus one other
    ...plus 23 instances involving out-of-scope types
    (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
* In the expression: foldr (\ x s -> s + 1) 0
  In an equation for `lengthList':
      lengthList = foldr (\ x s -> s + 1) 0
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: I can not reproduce this. Did you added a signature, or a made a call with this `lengthList`?

Comment: I just load one-line module with GHCi 8.4.3



~\Desktop\hskl> ghci .\lenListFoldr.hs
GHCi, version 8.4.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( lenListFoldr.hs, interpreted )

lenListFoldr.hs:1:14: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `t0' arising from a use of `foldr'
    ....

Comment: length:: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a    you need to explicit is Foldable

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It works straight away in GHCi due to the monomorphism restriction being disabled.

Comment: @duplode: aarrghh... yes :s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add type signature:

```
lengthList :: [a] -> Int
```

Or something similar. The error states: "Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `t0' should be." In other words, the compiler could not infer the type. Or, as a comment states: use the function in a context, then the compiler will use the context to infer correct type for `lengthList`. I believe the function `foldr` uses a class constraint `Foldable t`; in your case, the compiler doesn't know what `lengthList` is folding. By giving the signature above, you bound `t0` to be a list. Take a look at the output GHCi gives for

```
:t foldr
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

In short, GHC can figure out that `a` is unused and `b` is a `Num`, but it does not know `t`.

Answer (score 3):

It can be solved by type definition:

```
lengthList :: (Foldable t, Num a1) => t a2 -> a1
```

It strange, but if just paste function to interpreter, it will be works fine without type definition

Comment: "It strange, but if just paste function to interpreter, it will be works fine without type definition" -- That is because GHCi by default disables [the monomorphism restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32496864/2751851).