# Get Column in Haskell CSV and infer the column type

Tags: csv, haskell

I'm exploring a csv file in an interactive ghci session (in a jupyter notebook):

```
import Text.CSV
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

dat <- parseCSVFromFile "/home/user/data.csv"
headers = head dat
records = tail dat

-- define a way to get a particular row by index
indexRow :: [[Field]] -> Int -> [Field]
indexRow csv index = csv !! index

indexRow records 1
-- this works! 

-- Now, define a way to get a particular column by index
indexField :: [[Field]] -> Int -> [Field]
indexField records index = map (\x -> x !! index) records
```

While this works if I know in advance the type of column 3:

```
map (\x -> read x :: Double) $ indexField records 3
```

How can I ask `read` to infer what the type might be when for example my columns could contain strings or num?  I'd like it to try for me, but:

```
map read $ indexField records 3
```

fails with

```
Prelude.read: no parse
```

I don't care whether they are string or num, I just need that they are all the same and I am failing to find a way to specify that generally with the read function at least.

Weirdly, if I define a mean function like so:

```
mean :: Fractional a => [a] -> Maybe a
mean [] = Nothing
mean [x] = Just x
mean xs = Just (sum(xs) / (fromIntegral (length xs)))
```

This works:

```
mean $ map read $ indexField records 2
Just 13.501359655240003
```

But without the mean, this still fails:

```
map read $ indexField records 2
Prelude.read: no parse
```

Comment: try `(map read $ indexField records 2)::(Read a, Fractional a)=>[a]`. Moreover, if your columns could contain strings or num, you cannot put them in list, since the element of list must be same type.

Comment: @assembly.jc, I expect data to be consistent within a column, so there won't be mixed types, but I do expect each column may be different from each other column--column 1 is integers, columns 2 is doubles, column 3 is strings, etc.  (Or if there is a mix within a column, you'd have to infer a list of strings.)

Comment: @Zeta this is noted.

Comment: Even though the data type is consistent within a column, you still need to specify the type for `read`, or it can be inferred from context, for example: `sum $ map read $ indexField records 2`, compiler know you want numeric type and try to pick one of numeric type for you, in above example, it will try `Integer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `read` is at the end of its wits when it comes to situations like this. Let's revisit `read`:

```
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

As you can see, `a` doesn't depend on the input, but solely on the output, and therefore of the context of our function. If you use `read a + read b`, then the additional `Num` context will limit the types to `Integer` or `Double` due to `default` rules. Let's see it in action:

```
> :set +t
> read "1234"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
> read "1234" + read "1234"
2468
it :: (Num a, Read a) => a
```

Ok, `a` is still not helpful. Is there any type that we can read without additional context? Sure, unit:

```
> read "()"
()
it :: Read a => a
```

That's still not helpful at all, so let's enable the [monomorphism restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32496864/1139697):

```
> :set -XMonomorphismRestriction
> read "1234" + read "1234"
2468
it :: Integer
```

Aha. In the end, we had an `Integer`. Due to `+`, we had to decide on a type. Now, with the `MonomorphismRestriction` enabled, what happens on `read "1234"` without additional context?

```
> read "1234"
<interactive>:20:1
   No instance for (Read a0) arising from a use of 'read'
   The type variable 'a0' is ambiguous
```

Now GHCi doesn't pick any (default) type and forces *you* to chose one. Which makes the underlying error much more clear.

So how do we fix this? As CSV can contain arbitrary fields at run-time and all types are determined statically, we have to cheat by introducing something like

```
data CSVField = CSVString String | CSVNumber Double | CSVUnknown
```

and then write

```
parse :: Field -> CSVField
```

After all, our type needs to cover *all* possible fields.

However, in your case, we can just restrict `read's` type:

```
myRead :: String -> Double
myRead = read
```

But that's not wise, as we can still end up with errors if the column doesn't contain `Double`s to begin with. So instead, let's use `readMaybe` and `mapM`:

```
columnAsNumbers :: [Field] -> Maybe [Double]
columnAsNumbers = mapM readMaybe
```

That way, the type is fixed, and we're forced to check whether we have `Just` something or `Nothing`:

```
mean <$> columnAsNumbers (indexFields records 2)
```

If you find yourself often using `columnAsNumbers` create an operator, though:

```
(!!$) :: [[Field]] -> Maybe [Double]
records !!$ index = columnAsNumbers $ indexFields records index
```