# Using Either in a lookup where no key exists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, switch-statement, either

I'm following along with this:

https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/basics-of-haskell/10_Error_Handling#either-may-be-better-than-maybe

And I am trying to get a column of data from a CSV by variable name in the headers, earlier part given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956462/get-column-in-haskell-csv-and-infer-the-column-type).

Here's my code:

```
import Text.CSV
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

dat <- parseCSVFromFile "/home/user/data.csv"
headers = head dat
records = tail dat

indexField :: [[Field]] -> Int -> [Field]
indexField records index = map (\x -> x !! index) records
```

which works:

```
Prelude> indexField records 0
[1,2,3]
```

And headers are as follows:

```
Prelude> headers
["id", "category", "value"]
```

I have the following to index by field **name** rather than **index**

```
indexFieldbyName :: [[Field]] -> String -> [Field]
indexFieldbyName records indexName = indexField records (fromJust (elemIndex indexName headers))
```

Which also works:

```
Prelude> indexFieldbyName records "id"
[1,2,3]
```

However, I want this to fail more informatively when the key is not found in `headers`:

```
Prelude> indexFieldbyName records "meow"
Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
```

Here are my attempts:

```
indexFieldbyName2 :: [[Field]] -> String -> Either String [Field]
indexFieldbyName2 records indexName = indexField records index
  where index = case (elemIndex indexName headers) of
    Just v -> Right (v)
    Nothing -> Left ("Index not found")

Parse error (line 31, column 5): parse error on input ‘Just’
```

And

```
indexFieldbyName3 :: [[Field]] -> String -> Either String [Field]
indexFieldbyName3 records indexName = indexField records index
 where index = case v of
   Just (elemIndex indexName headers) -> Right (v)
   Nothing -> Left ("Index not found")

Parse error (line 44, column 4): parse error on input ‘Just’

indexFieldbyName4 :: [[Field]] -> String -> Either String [Field]
indexFieldbyName4 records indexName = indexField records index
 where index = case v of
   Just v -> Right (elemIndex indexName headers)
   Nothing -> Left ("Index not found")

Parse error (line 37, column 4): parse error on input ‘Just’
```

The above were indentation issues, the `just` had to be to the right of the `case`.  Now I have:

```
indexFieldbyName2' :: [[Field]] -> String -> Either String [Field]
indexFieldbyName2' records indexName = indexField records index
    where index = case (elemIndex indexName headers) of
                     Just v -> Right (v)
                     Nothing -> Left ("Index not found")

<interactive>:4:39: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Either String [Field]’ with actual type ‘[Field]’
    • In the expression: indexField records index
      In an equation for ‘indexFieldbyName2’:
          indexFieldbyName2 records indexName
            = indexField records index
            where
                index
                  = case (elemIndex indexName headers) of
                      Just v -> Right (v)
                      Nothing -> Left ("Index not found")
<interactive>:4:58: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Either String Int’
    • In the second argument of ‘indexField’, namely ‘index’
      In the expression: indexField records index
      In an equation for ‘indexFieldbyName2’:
          indexFieldbyName2 records indexName
            = indexField records index
            where
                index
                  = case (elemIndex indexName headers) of
                      Just v -> Right (v)
                      Nothing -> Left ("Index not found")
```

Comment: How are you using <- from do notation at the top level? (As in, `
dat <- parseCSVFromFile "/home/user/data.csv"` )

Comment: I'm in a ghci/ihaskell/jupyter notebook session.  When I change this to an equals sign, I get many errors later, I guess as it's looking for an IO wrapper.

Comment: I'm not at the machine so can't test.  Are you sure indentation is correct? IMO Just and Nothing need to be indented to be right of the i of index (say two spaces).  Besides the first implementation would look good  to me.

Comment: for the other question you need to stay in the functor -  use fmap or <$>. e.g.: `(indexField records) <$> index`

Comment: That solves it.  If you write that as an answer I'd happily accept.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the solving happened in the discussion.

It turns out there were two issues:

First indentation was wrong. There are is a little read at [haskell wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation).  In short when the code is in the same line as the `where` the following lines need to start at the same character as the first word after the where.  But since the Just/Nothing belongs to the case in the previous line another level of indentation was needed.

Second was a common occurrence when dealing with functors.  The return type was no longer an `Int` but an `f Int`.  So `indexField records index` needs to be rewritten to `fmap (indexField records) index`.  Or since this is a common pattern it got an operator `<$>` so to `(indexField records) <$> index`. (Think about that you could also write the original statement as `(indexField records) $ index`).

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning up your function, you have:

```
indexFieldbyName2' :: [[Field]] -> String -> Either String [Field]
indexFieldbyName2' records indexName = indexField records index
    where index = case elemIndex indexName headers of
                     Just v -> Right v
                     Nothing -> Left "Index not found"
```

The type of `index` is an `Either String Int` while `indexField records` requires a `Int`.  You can write another `case`, or use `fmap`, but you might find the code more readable straight-line:

```
indexFieldbyName3 :: [[Field]] -> String -> Either String [Field]
indexFieldbyName3 records indexName =
    case elemIndex indexName headers of
       Just v  -> Right (indexField records v)
       Nothing -> Left "Index not found"
```

Or using more helper functions like `maybe` instead of `case`:

```
indexFieldbyName4 :: [[Field]] -> String -> Either String [Field]
indexFieldbyName4 records indexName =
    let midx = elemIndex indexName headers
        err  = Left "Index not found"
    in maybe err (Right . indexField records) midx
```

N.B. Answer typed, not tested.