# Ambiguous type variable when using Tagless Final approach

Tags: haskell, types

I'm using template haskell to construct an integer which is tagged with its value at the type level:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell TypeOperators, DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}

module TNat where

import GHC.TypeLits
import Language.Haskell.TH

data TNat (a::Nat) = TN Int deriving Show

zero = (TN 0 :: TNat 0)

inc :: TNat n -> TNat (n + 1)
inc (TN n) = TN (n + 1)

-- usage: fromNat @5
mkNat :: Int -> Q Exp
mkNat 0 = [| zero |]
mkNat n = [| inc ($(mkNat (n - 1))) |]
```

I am using this in a tagless final style dsl of which I have made an examplar version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, DataKinds, FlexibleContexts, TypeApplications, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances, ExistentialQuantification, FlexibleInstances, GADTs #-}

{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Test where

import TNat
import Text.Printf
import Language.Haskell.TH
import GHC.TypeLits

data IntList (ls :: [*])

class SYM repr where
    nat :: TNat a -> repr (TNat a)
    ret :: repr b -> repr (IntList '[b])
    comp :: repr a -> repr (IntList ls) -> repr (IntList (a ': ls))

newtype S a = S{unS :: String}
instance SYM S where
    nat (TN i) = S $ show i
    ret e1 = S $ unS e1
    comp e1 e2 = S $ (unS e1) ++ " " ++ (unS e2)
```

The issue is that the following statement is failing with an ambiguous type `repr0` rather than the more general `repr`:

```
t1 = ret $ nat $(mkNat 2)
```

The specific error message is:

> ```
> * Ambiguous type variable `repr0' arising from a use of `r et'
>   prevents the constraint `(SYM repr0)' from being solved.
>   Relevant bindings include
>     t1 :: repr0 (IntList '[TNat 2]) (bound at test.hs:35:1 )
>   Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `rep r0' should be.
>   These potential instance exist:
>     instance SYM S -- Defined at test.hs:29:10
> * In the expression: ret $ nat (inc (inc zero))
>   In an equation for `t1': t1 = ret $ nat (inc (inc zero))    | 35 | t1 = ret $ nat $(mkNat 2)    |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

I feel that I am missing some key part of the declaration of the DSL, or that it is a odd interaction between Template Haskell and this style of writing DSLs (since I didn't have this issue with previous versions without TH).

Comment: I believe you've run across the monomorphism restriction. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction) is a good StackOverflow explanation of the phenomenon, and [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-930004.5.5) is the Haskell language specification section on it. In GHC, you can disable the restriction with `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction`, but it would make more sense to just add a type annotation explicitly.