# 'Referencing' typeclass functions

Tags: haskell, monomorphism-restriction

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to use [Hoed](https://wiki.haskell.org/Hoed) to trace Haskell evaluations, because maybe it will further help my learning process.

I saw in their examples code like this

```
isEven :: Int -> Bool
isEven = observe "isEven" isEven'
isEven' n = mod2 n == 0
```

I was thinking how could I `observe` in order to trace an instance defined function like `>>=` for example.

I wrote something like

`bind' = observe "bind'" (>>=)`

and of course I've got an error

```
* Ambiguous type variable 'm0' arising from a use of '>>='
  prevents the constraint '(Monad m0)' from being solved.
  Relevant bindings include
    bind' :: m0 a0 -> (a0 -> m0 b0) -> m0 b0 (bound at my.hs:46:1)
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what 'm0' should be.
  These potential instances exist:
  ...
```

Should I / How could I use a type annotation in order to specify which `Monad` instance's (e.g. Reader, State etc.) `>>=` function

Comment: Perhaps you just need a type signature on `bind'`? It looks like `observe` (like `Debug.Trace.trace`) is "pure", so the signature should be `bind' ::  Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`

Comment: It worked. This was so silly... thank you!

Comment: @crokeea If you wish, add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have found the [infamous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction) `MonomorphismRestriction`. [More](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) [info](http://lambda.jstolarek.com/2012/05/towards-understanding-haskells-monomorphism-restriction/). The links do a great job of explaining what the MonomorphismRestriction is and how it works.

You're not wrong to expect that writing `bind'` with no signature should "just work". However, sometimes the compiler needs a bit of help. In short, due to the MonomorphismRestriction, GHC tries to take the nominally polymorphic signature of `bind' :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, and make it less polymorphic by instantiating some of the type variables.

In your case, it looks like the compiler wants to make `bind'` only work for one specific `Monad m`. Without your real code, I can't say for sure, but consider this example:

```
import Debug.Trace

main :: IO ()
main = (>>=) (return "hello") print

bind' = trace "bind" (>>=)
```

The compiler produces an error similar to yours: `Ambiguous type variable m0`

However, if you *use* `bind'`:

```
import Debug.Trace

main :: IO ()
main = bind' (return "hello") print

bind' = trace "bind" (>>=)
```

no error! That's because GHC is *inferring* that `m` should be `IO` since `bind'` is used in the `IO` monad.

Alternatively, you can tell GHC to turn off the MonomorphismRestriction:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Debug.Trace

main :: IO ()
main = (>>=) (return "hello") print

bind' = trace "bind" (>>=)
```

and it compiles just fine!