# Change variable type to match the expected type

Tags: haskell, types, type-mismatch

In the following code, I get the error

> Couldn't match type 'Integer' with 'Int'
>   Expected type :[(Test, [Test])]
>   Actual type : [(Integer, [Integer])]

when executing

```
testFunc test
```

with the following declaration

```
type TestType = Int
a = [(1,[2,3])]

testFunc :: [(TestType ,[TestType])] -> TestType 
testFunc ((a,(b:c)):d) = a
```

How do I declare my list `a` so that it matches the type of `testFunc`?

And is there a way to fix the error without modifying `type Test = Int` or the declaration of `a`?

Comment: How about `a = [(1::Int,[2::Int,3])]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the monomorphism restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I declare my list 'test' so that it matches the type of testFunc?

Well, by declaring this as the type.

```
a :: [(TestType, [TestType])]
a = [(1,[2,3])]
```

Generally speaking, you should always give explicit type signatures for top-level definitions like this. Without such a signature, the compiler will pick one for you. Generally Haskell tries to pick the most general available type possible; in this case that would be

```
a :: (Num a, Num b) => [(a, [b])]
```

...which would include both `[(Int, [Int])]` and `[(Integer, [Integer])]`. However, the [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) restricts the type by default, excluding such polymorphism. So GHC has to pick one version, and the default one is `Integer`, not `Int`.

The right solution, again, is to provide an explicit signature. However, you can also turn off the monomorphism restriction:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

type TestType = Int
a = [(1,[2,3])]

testFunc :: [(TestType ,[TestType])] -> TestType 
testFunc ((x,(y:z)):w) = x

main :: IO ()
main = print $ testFunc a
```

Comment: The `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` isn't necessary in your last example; the same code works just fine without it. When you call `testFunc a` in the same source file that you define `a`, then the monomorphism restriction infers `a :: [(TestType, [TestType])]`. The monomorphism restriction won't pick `Integer` over `Int` if the only use sites require `Int`, as in your example. I suspect the OP was calling the function in GHCi after loading a file containing `testFunc` and `a`.

Comment: @Ben interesting, I actually didn't know that it does that over top-level bindings. This isn't something I would ever rely on though – moving that definition to another module would change the type inference! Better always give a signature.

Comment: I definitely agree that the right solution is to give a type signature.