# Why use null function instead of == [] to check for empty list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, is-empty, empty-list

I am reading through the "Starting Out" chapter of [*Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out). It says:

> `null` checks if a list is empty. If it is, it returns **`True`**, otherwise it returns **`False`**. Use this function instead of **`xs == []`** (if you have a list called **`xs`**)

I tried in ghci:

```
xs = []      -- and then,

xs == []
null xs
```

Both of them are `True`.

I wonder what's the difference.

Should I use the `null` function instead of `== []` and why?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You should use `null`. In most cases it doesn't matter, but it is a good habit to get into anyway, because occasionally you may want to check if a list of non-comparable things is empty. Here is a short, crisp example showing this difference:

```
> null [id]
False
> [id] == []
<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • No instance for (Eq (a0 -> a0)) arising from a use of ‘==’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In the expression: [id] == []
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = [id] == []
```

Comment: “In most cases it doesn't matter” – I'd disagree. It's very common to write polymorphic list functions, which shouldn't require an `Eq` constraint (even if they will indeed in most cases be _instantiated_ with `Eq` types).

Comment: I agree with everything written in this answer. For the sake of posterity and completeness, it may also be worth mentioning why `length xs == 0` is a bad idea.

Comment: For the record: `length xs == 0` is a bad idea because it needs to traverse the whole linked list (which is `O(n)` and never terminates on an infinte list).

Answer (score 53):

There is a difference. In order to use `x == []`, the type of the elements of the list should be a member of the [**`Eq`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq) typeclass. Indeed, checking the equality of two lists is defined by the instance declaration:

```
instance Eq a => Eq [a] where
    []     == []      =  True
    (x:xs) == (y:ys)  =  x == y  &&  xs == ys
    _      == _       =  False
```

That means that you can not use `x == []` if `x` is for example a list of `IO Int`s.

[**`null :: [a] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:null) on the other hand, uses pattern matching. This is [implemented as](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#null):

> ```
> null                    :: [a] -> Bool
> null []                 =  True
> null (_:_)              =  False
> ```

So regardless what type the elements of the list are, it will always  typecheck.

Answer (score 28):

In addition to the good answers given so far, `null` actually has type

```hs
null :: Foldable t => t a -> Bool
```

I don't know if you've gotten to typeclasses in LYAH, but the short of it is that `null` can be used not just for lists, but for any data structure that implements `null`.

This is to say that using `null` on a [`Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html) or a [`Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Set.html) is valid, too.

```
> null Map.empty
True
> null (Map.singleton 1)
False
> null Set.empty
True
> null (Set.singleton 1)
False
> null []
True
> null [1]
False
```

I don't think it's especially common to write functions that need to be this general, but it doesn't hurt to default to writing more general code.

## A side note

In many cases, you'll end up wanting to use a function like `null` to do conditional behavior on a list (or other data structure). If you already know that your input is a specific data structure, it's more elegant to just pattern match on its empty case.

Compare

```hs
myMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
myMap f xs
  | null xs = []
myMap f (x:xs) = f x : myMap f xs
```

to

```hs
myMap' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
myMap' f [] = []
myMap' f (x:xs) = f x : myMap' f xs
```

In general, you should try to prefer pattern matching if it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Also a simple function that filter all empty list would fail:

```
withoutEmpty = filter (== [])
```

and that would be:

```
withoutEmpty = filter null
```

notice that:

```
withoutEmpty ls = filter (==[]) ls
```

will work just fine, but the important point is that in some cases like the other one could fail.

Also look at @cole answer, it complements all the answers here, the typeclass Foldable has the `null` function there to be implemented:

To see more info of [Foldable here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html)

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading. `withoutEmpty = filter (==[])` may cause an error, but `withoutEmpty x = filter (==[]) x` works fine.

Comment: @DanielWagner (or Damian) could either of you elaborate why only the point-free version fails to type-check?

Comment: @LeifWillerts [What is the monomorphism restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32496864/791604)