# What is wrong with my Longest Common Subsequence Haskell function?

Tags: haskell, dynamic-programming

I've been following Haskell tutorials online, and I think it's really cool that the `head, tail, init`, and `last` are all built-in. I thought as a test, it'd be really cool if I could write the Longest Common Subsequence algorithm in one line. My code is as follows:

`lcs x y = if length x == 0 || length y == 0 then 0 else if (last x) == (last y) then (lcs (init x) (init y))+1 else (lcs (init x) y + lcs x (init y))`

I've applied parenthesis liberally, but when I call `lcs "abc" "abd"` I get `6`, which obviously isn't right.

Comment: You've tagged this question with as "dynamic programming", but this algorithm is not the dynamic programming algorithm and will be **slow**. Don't expect the compiler to automatically convert this to the dynamic programming algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `max`, not `+`, in your `else` branch. Using [`length` instead of `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57029258/791604) and `last`/`init` instead of `head`/`tail` will also be noticeably slower. The idiomatic form would look like this:

```
lcs [] _ = 0
lcs _ [] = 0
lcs xs@(x:xt) ys@(y:yt)
    | x == y = lcs xt yt + 1
    | otherwise = max (lcs xs yt) (lcs xt ys)
```

I've replaced the uses of `null`, `head`, and `tail` with pattern matching, as is common. The single-line version is likely more readable using those functions than using pattern matching, which is why I mentioned them at all.

You will get another, much more significant speed boost by memoizing this function, e.g. using an array or similar.