# `trace` function in ghci does not print on second invocation

Tags: haskell, ghci

## Problem:

The trace function does not work on the second invocation but this only happens if the function containing trace is loaded into ghci.

## Question

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I load in Haskel modules and still have the expected behaviour?

## Unexpected behaviour:

I have a file called `test.hs`

```hs
import Debug.Trace (trace)
main = trace "test" return "main is called"
```

Then I type following in ghci. Note on the second invocation of `main` `trace` did not print "test"

```
Prelude> :l test
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> main
test
"main is called"
*Main> main      -- No output from trace?
"main is called"
```

## Expected behaviour

However, if I type the main function in ghci, I get the expected behaviour

```
Prelude> import Debug.Trace (trace)
Prelude Debug.Trace> main = trace "test" return "main is called" 
Prelude Debug.Trace> main
test
"main is called"
Prelude Debug.Trace> main -- Output from trace
test
"main is called"
Prelude Debug.Trace>
```

## Update

@Robin Zigmond suggestion, I tried out different parenthesis but without success

```
main = trace "test" (return "main is called")
main = return(trace "test" "main is called") -- Joins the outputs into one string
```

Comment: I don't think I fully understand this behaviour - `trace` is a tricky thing, because it basically breaks the normal rules of Haskell in order to give you a debugging tool. But I wonder if the behaviour would change if you bracketed the expression I would, as `main = trace "test" (return "main is called")`. Or perhaps as `main = return (trace "test" "main is called")`. Your version is actually parsed as `main = (trace "test" return) "main is called"` so I suspect the function `trace "test" return` is only needing to be evaluated once.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions without success.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, a general idea of how Haskell evaluates things. Consider this expression

```
(\x -> x * x) (2 + 2)
```

Haskell is lazy; functions don't evaluate their arguments before invocation, so a naive way of doing this would be:

```
(2 + 2) * (2 + 2)
```

But that would double the work!

What is done instead is something like:

```
    *
   /  \
   \  /
   (2+2)
```

That is, the runtime remembers that `2 + 2` came from a single place, and when it's evaluated, the result is reused in other parts of the expression:

```
    *
   /  \
   \  /
     4
```

and then

```
     16
```

The `trace` function wraps an expression and only prints the message the *first* time the expression is "popped". It doesn't print the message again if the result is requested again:

```
ghci> (\x -> x * x) (trace "pop!" (2 + 2))
pop!
16
```

The next part of the puzzle are `IO` actions. In Haskell, statement-like things like `IO` actions are actually values like anything else. They can be passed as arguments to functions, and they can be returned from functions. It's just that the runtime interprets them as descriptions of effectful actions to perform in the real world.

Therefore, expressions whose type is `IO something` must be *evaluated* (in the pure, lazy sense) before being *executed* (in the "interacts with the world" sense). For example:

```
(\x -> x >> x) (trace "test" (putStrLn "foo"))
```

becomes

```
        (>>)
       /  \
       \  /
(trace "test" (putStrLn "foo"))
```

here we pop the expression and "test" is printed a single time

```
        (>>)
       /  \
       \  /
    putStrLn "foo"
```

the runtime sees something like

```
putStrLn "foo", then putStrLn "foo" again
```

Actually, what you wrote is slightly different: `(trace "test" return) "main is called"`. In your code `trace` is wrapping the `return` function, not the resulting `IO String` value. But the effect is similar, functions are also values in Haskell. Expressions whose type is a function must be evaluated before the function is called.

Also, in your case, what's happening is that the `main` action is evaluated once, and executed several times.

Notice that `trace`'s effects (printing stuff on console) are out-of-band with the normal flow of `IO` actions. They happen according to the vagaries of lazy evaluation. It's a debug function that shouldn't be used for "real" work.

---

**Update**: I forgot to answer this part of the question: why does `trace` have the behavior you expect in your ghci experiments?

`trace "test" (return "foo")` is a polymorphic value, it doesn't actually specify a concrete monad (try `:t return "foo"`). ghci's [defaulting rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#i-o-actions-at-the-prompt) instantiate it to `IO` before executing it. This polymorphism makes ghci recalculate the value each time you enter `main`. The effect should disappear if you provide an explicit type annotation, like `main = (trace "test" (return "foo")) :: IO String`.

Comment: You are correct. When `main` is loaded from file it has type `IO()` but when typed in ghci `main` has the type `Monad m => m [Char]` instead.

Comment: @ChuanyuanLiu There's a language extension called the `MonomorphismRestriction`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction If you activate it in ghci (`:set -XMonomorphismRestriction`) polymorphic bindings like `let main = return "foo"` cease to be allowed. The restriction is deactivated by default  in ghci https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/3202 but one consequence of it being deactivated is sometimes unexpected re-computation of values, like your polymorphic `main`.