# How can I download a file from the Internet using Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm just trying to do something similar to `wget`, where I download a file from the Internet. I saw that there used to be a package called [http-wget](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-wget), but that it's been deprecated in favor of http-conduit.

Http-conduit has [a simple example](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.3.8/docs/Network-HTTP-Simple.html) for how to get the contents of a web page using `httpBS`. So following that, I got this to work:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.HTTP.Simple
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let url = "https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml"
  resp <- httpBS url
  B8.putStrLn $ getResponseBody resp
```

And this works for getting the filename (sitemap.xml) from the URL:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.HTTP.Simple
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let url = "https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml"
  let urlParts = B8.split '/' $ B8.pack url
  let fileName = Prelude.last urlParts
  B8.putStrLn fileName
```

But I can't put them together:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.HTTP.Simple
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let url = "https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml"
  let urlParts = B8.split '/' $ B8.pack url
  let fileName = Prelude.last urlParts
  resp <- httpBS url
  B8.putStrLn $ getResponseBody resp
```

That gives the error:

```
ny1920-parse.hs:12:41: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Request’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: Request
    • In the first argument of ‘B8.pack’, namely ‘url’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘B8.pack url’
      In the expression: B8.split '/' $ B8.pack url
   |
12 |   let urlParts = B8.split '/' $ B8.pack url
   |                                         ^^^
```

So I just need to convert `String -> Request`? There's apparently [a function for that in http-conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.7.8/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:parseRequest_), but it doesn't work as expected—I still get the same error.

I can force the URL to be a Request like this:

```hs
  let url = "https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml" :: Request
```

But then of course that breaks the part where I break up the filename, because it expects a `[Char]` and not a `Request`.

So I'm stuck—if I make the URL a String, it breaks http-conduit. And if I make it a Request, it breaks the string manipulation.

I feel like something this simple shouldn't be this hard, no?

Edit: Ok, so I can almost get it to work with this addition:

```hs
  let urlParts = B8.split '/' $ B8.pack (show url)
```

That compiles, but it makes the filename corrupt. Trying to print out the filename gives: `"1.1\n}\n"` instead of `sitemap.xml`.

Comment: There is also https://hackage.haskell.org/package/req with a more interesting API

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the monomorphism restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Looking at this again 2 months later, it's really just the monomorphism restriction that keeps the original code from working. I'll leave this here as a more specific workaround for this case, as opposed to the general workarounds for the monomorphism restiction.

---

Try this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.HTTP.Simple
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let url = "https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml"
  let urlParts = B8.split '/' $ B8.pack url
  let fileName = Prelude.last urlParts
  req <- parseRequest url
  resp <- httpBS req
  B8.putStrLn $ getResponseBody resp
```

You can't have `url` simultaneously be a `String` for `B8.pack` and a `Request` for `httpBS`. By calling `parseRequest` manually to get a `Request` instead of letting the `IsString` instance do it, we now have `url :: String` and `req :: Request`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to disagree with the other answer here: splitting on `/` yourself is a bad idea. Don't try to implement an ad-hoc URL parser; it's way harder than you think. Instead, re-use the parse that you *already have*:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.HTTP.Client
import Network.HTTP.Simple
import Network.URI
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let request = "https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml"
        fileName = Prelude.last . pathSegments . getUri $ request
    resp <- httpBS request
    B8.putStrLn $ getResponseBody resp
```

See [the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-uri-2.6.4.1/docs/Network-URI.html#t:URI) for more on the parts you can extract from a URI.