# GHC causes type mismatch by selecting the wrong type for a literal

Tags: haskell

Just today I discovered that when GHC (v8.8.4) puts a type to a value literal, it sometimes "guesses wrong" and causes type mismatches later on.  Here's a minimal (non)working example:

```hs
die :: (Integral a) => [a] -- If this line is commented out, compilation fails
die = [1..6]

-- Generate a list representing the multiset of all possible
-- rolls on n six-sided dice, summing each roll, such that each
-- possible roll has as many instances in the list as there are
-- valid rolls that add up to that number.
dieRolls :: Integral a => a -> [a]
dieRolls 0 = [0]
dieRolls n = [newRoll + oldSum |
    newRoll <- die, 
    oldSum <- dieRolls $ n-1]

main = do print $ dieRolls 2
```

As written, this compiles and runs as expected. But if I comment out the first line, I'm told this:

```
mnwe.hs:9:25: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          dieRolls :: forall a. Integral a => a -> [a]
        at mnwe.hs:7:1-34
    • In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘oldSum’
      In the expression: newRoll + oldSum
      In the expression:
        [newRoll + oldSum | newRoll <- die, oldSum <- dieRolls $ n - 1]
    • Relevant bindings include
        oldSum :: a (bound at mnwe.hs:11:5)
        n :: a (bound at mnwe.hs:9:10)
        dieRolls :: a -> [a] (bound at mnwe.hs:8:1)
  |
9 | dieRolls n = [newRoll + oldSum |
  |
```

What seems to be happening is that, in the absence of an explicit type declaration, GHC is inferring that the elements of `[1..6]` are, not just any old integers, but specifically of the `Integer` type. This leads `(+)` to expect a second argument that it can guarantee will likewise have the type of `Integer`, which it can't do when the output of `dieRolls` is explicitly identified as `Integral a => [a]`. Another working version of the program is one that eliminates the `die` variable altogether and substitutes `[1..6]` directly into the body of `dieRolls`, so it seems like the problem starts when that variable is defined.

I don't understand this behavior. Why is GHC inferring that `die` is specifically supposed to be a list of capital-I `Integers`? Isn't that a violation of lazy evaluation? And why does it pick `Integer` here when GHCi tells me this:

```
GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :t [1..6]
[1..6] :: (Num a, Enum a) => [a]
Prelude> die = [1..6]
Prelude> :t die
die :: (Num a, Enum a) => [a]
```

Does type inference just work differently in GHCi?

Comment: This is the [monomorphism restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction) (combined with type defaulting).  The restriction causes a monomorphic type to be inferred for `die`, and type defaulting causes that type to be defaulted to `[Integer]`.  In recent GHC versions, the restriction is by default turned off in GHCi but turned on when compiling with GHC.  You can turn it off with a `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` pragma.

Comment: The monomorphism restriction is generally irrelevant for compiled files though, because top-level bindings should always have an explicit signature. Either add the signature, or move `die` into a `where` block associated to `dieRolls`.